# Perl script that invokes shell command doesn't work

Tags: perl, shell

I am writing a simple Perl program to test a shell script for changing directory. But it doesn't work.

This is my code :

```
$result = `cd/`;
print $result;
```

It works fine when I use

```
$result =`dir`;
```

Comment: You need to be more  specific than "doesn't work". Do you get an error? Can you show us expected and actual output?

Comment: \`cd /\`  not \`cd/\`

Comment: The problem with Perl is sometimes if there is an error, it doesn't print it. Rather it waits for next command. So I am not sure about it.
But I expected that my program would have changed the directory, which it does not.

Comment: even \`cd /\` doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to change the cwd directory in your script, then you should use Perl's built-in `chdir` function.
[perldoc -f chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html)

Answer (score 3):

`cd` (by default) *doesn't output anything*, so you're assigning an *empty string* to your `$result` variable.

If you want to *output* the (full) path of the directory you changed to, simply append `&& pwd` inside the backticks:

```
 $result = `cd / && pwd`;
```

Note that [`` `...` ``](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) creates a *child process* for running the shell with the specified command, so whatever environment changes you perform there - including changing the directory - do NOT affect the Perl script itself.

In other words: you're NOT changing the *Perl script*'s current directory with your shell command.

---

If your intent is:

- to **simply *test* whether the shell command you enclose in `` `...` `` *succeeds*** or not, use, the [`system()` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) instead; e.g.:

  ```
      system('cd /') == 0 || die "Command failed";
  ```
- to ***capture* the output from the shell command**, presume it to be a directory path and **[change the *Perl* script's working directory](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html)** to it:

  ```
      $result = `cd / && pwd` || die "Command failed.";
      chomp $result; # trim trailing newline

      # Change Perl script's working dir.
      chdir $result || die "Could not change to $result.";
  ```

Answer (score 2):

To affect the current working directory of the perl process, use the [chdir()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) function.